# Disabling/enabling carrier options by city in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

Im using Prestashop 1.5.6 and I'd need to disable a carrier option if it's outside the company's city, if a customer lives in the same city than the company's city it should display as carrier the company's carrier, and if the customer lives outside the same city than the company's city it should show a third party carrier.

is this possible to do it with the functionality of the shop itself, is there a module , a workaround or something? I thought setting the city as a "zone" and then assigning the company's carrier to that zone only might do the work, but it doesnt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can not achieve it by the exist system. but i hope it can be achieve by a module. but till now i don't find any module for your problem. If we create the module means then we can achieve

Comment: yeah, I just was seeing the zone is stored by "state"